# Error backing up symmetric key in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following statement to backup symmetric key in order to migrate the database to another server:

```
BACKUP SYMMETRIC KEY PEK
   TO  FILE = 'c:\symmetric_key' 
   ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '3dH85Hhk003GHk2597gheij4';
```

I am getting the following error when I run the above statement.

```
Incorrect syntax near 'SYMMETRIC'.
```

Any ideas  how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2022?

Comment: SQL Server version is 15.0.2000.5

Comment: Like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/backup-symmetric-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) kindly explains, `BACKUP SYMMETRIC KEY` is available from version 16.0.

Comment: Is there any other way to migrate the symmetric key from this server to a new server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of backing up, I created a new key.

[Create identical symmetric keys on two servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/create-identical-symmetric-keys-on-two-servers?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Instead of only adding a link which may become stale with time, it would be helpful if you could add a more detailed answer with some of the steps you took and then, if you'd like to add extra information, include the link to the documentation.